# InfoPath and SharePoint language changes

Tags: list, infopath, form, language

We are trying to use SharePoint 2013 and InfoPath as an incident reporting system for a global company.  Is there a way to allow users in countries using languages other than English to view and enter data in their language, and have it automatically translate to English (or other) as users with a different language set up view it?  The idea is to have 1 form, 1 list associated with that form for the whole system. I realize this is a long shot, just looking for any ideas.